# 14.04 Multi-GPU Multi-Monitor NVIDIA, tried every guide please help

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

```
Asus Z10PE-D8 WS

2x Intel Xeon E5-2697 V3

128GB DDR4 ECC

3x EVGA GTX 980 (SLI)

Ubuntu 14.04
3.19.0-28-generic
```

system drive is encrypted

I've followed every guide I can find online. First I couldn't boot (black screen) so I added nomodeset in grub and got to command prompt. So far I've tried using the ppa drivers, and nvidia proprietary drivers directly from nvidia. I've got them installed, and I can boot into a session, but I can't get my monitors to go above 640x480 resolution (they're 1920x1200 monitors). I've used linux before and I'm comfortable with the command line but I don't remember where everything is that might be needed to troubleshoot this, but I'm happy to provide more info if needed. Thanks for your help!